# Materialize side nav under Wordpress admin bar

Tags: css, wordpress, materialize

I'm making a new theme using Materialize, but an issue came up.
Below, I've added a screenshot of the issue.

[image: The issue]

Now my question is, how can I fix this?
I want the navbar to be under the admin bar completely.
I could use `padding` or `margin`, but that would show up when the admin bar is disabled (which it will be for all users but me).

I hope somebody could help me fix it :)

Cheers

EDIT: here, have the code I'm using (with some Wordpress stuff):

```html
<header>
    <div class="navbar-fixed">
        <nav> 
            <div class="nav-wrapper container"> 
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_home_url( null, null, 'relative' ) ); ?>" class="brand-img img-responsive">
                    <img src="https://www.finlaydag33k.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/logo-FDG-300-01-300x300.png">
                </a>                 
                <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down"> 
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" data-activates="side-nav-150" class="button-collapse show-on-large"><i class="material-icons"><?php _e( 'menu', 'finlaydag33k' ); ?></i></a>
                    </li>                     
                </ul>                 
            </div>             
        </nav>
    </div>
    <ul class="side-nav" id="side-nav-150"> 
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
                'menu' => 'Main Menu',
                'container' => '',
                'fallback_cb' => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker()
        ) ); ?>
        <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'right_sidebar' ) ) : ?>
            <div id="sidebar">
                <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'right_sidebar' ); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?> 
    </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: When you are logged in, a class is added to the `body`. You can then use CSS to target the header when you are logged in.

Comment: hmm... I don't really know what I should do with it, but I can give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding `<?php body_class(); ?>` to the `<body>` tag fixed the issue for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your navbar class to navbar-fixed, this will offset your other content while making your nav fixed.

Comment: which one should I attach it to?  
`.navbar` (the one that contains my logo, and the button to open the side-nav) or the `.side-nav`?
As the `.navbar` already has the `navbar-fixed` class.
adding that to the `.side-nav` makes it so that the side-nav always shows

Comment: Try moving the sidenav outside of .navbar-fixed, as shown in the new answer

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the sidenav outside of .navbar-fixed

```
<header>
    <div class="navbar-fixed">
        <nav>
            <div class="nav-wrapper"> <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
                <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
                <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                    <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
                    <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
                    <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
                    <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>


    <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
        <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
        <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
        <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
        <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: I've updated my OP so you can see the code I'm using (I forgot to add that lol).  
As you can see, I already jave it pretty much like you do.